# MS Access 2010: Date Range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Note: SMonth is date to and SYear is date from. I just haven't changed the names but the format has already been changed to short date.

I've created a code in Microsoft Access Visual Basic to create a date  range but when I type the date range in both text boxes `SMonth` and `SYear`, it only shows the records with dates from `txtYear` and not the range date itself. This is the code.

```
'Date Range
ElseIf Me.SEmployeeName = "" And Me.Soo = False And Me.Scc = False And 
Me.SMonth <> "" And Me.SYear <> "" Then
Me.tbl_ALL_Query_subform.Form.RecordSource = "Select * from tbl_ALL where 
((((tbl_ALL.NTEDate ) <=  '" & Me.SMonth.Value & "') AND (tbl_ALL.NTEDate) >= 
'" & Me.SYear.Value & "')) "
```

Comment: You are comparing date with string, that's not correct. You should convert SMonth to date, then format a correct date for SQL in american format `#mm/dd/yyyy#`. I hope SMonth contains date?

Comment: @SergeyS. They are formatted as short date even though their names are `SMonth` and `SYear` because they were originally functioned to filter the month with the year but I've decided that date range will be better that is why I changed the format of the two text boxes to short date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your txtTo and txtFrom don't seem to come into play, so hard to tell.

However, you compare date with text, so adjust your query:

```
ElseIf Me.SEmployeeName = "" And _
    Me.Soo = False And Me.Scc = False And _
    Me.SMonth <> "" And Me.SYear <> "" Then

    Me!tbl_ALL_Query_subform.Form.RecordSource = _
    "Select * from tbl_ALL where Month(tbl_ALL.NTEDate) <= " & Me!SMonth.Value & " AND Year(tbl_ALL.NTEDate) >= " & Me!SYear.Value & ""
```

If *start date* and *end date*:

```
"Select * From tbl_ALL Where tbl_ALL.NTEDate Between #" & Format(Me!StartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!EndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: My txtTo is SMonth and the txtFrom is SYear. I just forgot didn't changed the text box name but I surely changed the format of both text boxes to short date.

Comment: I've tried your code but the result is still the same as the old one.

Comment: I suggest you change the names and variables to something meaningful.